# Function output redirection to file doesn't work in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a basic shell script which takes in `log*.zip` (as downloaded from GitHub actions), greps all matching lines in specific files, and outputs the matched lines in a tabular form. Here is (relevant) part of the source code:-

```bash
#!/bin/bash
....
    FILENAME=$1
    shift

    OUT_FN=$1
    shift

    PATTERN=$@
....

function print_content {
    LINE_LENGTH=130
    LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_FILENAME=$(($LINE_LENGTH-3)) # to save calculations in loop

    for file in ./*; do
        MATCHING_LINES=$(grep -n $PATTERN "$file" | cut -f1 -d:)
        [ -z "$MATCHING_LINES" ] && continue

        LONGEST_ML=$(wc -L <<< "$MATCHING_LINES")
        LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_LINE=$(($LINE_LENGTH-$LONGEST_ML-7))
        PRINTF_FORMAT="| %-"$LONGEST_ML"s | %-"$LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_LINE"s |\n"

        perl -E 'say "-" x '"$LINE_LENGTH"
        printf "| %-"$LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_FILENAME"s|\n" "$file"
        perl -E 'say "-" x '"$LINE_LENGTH"

        while IFS= read -r line; do
            LINE_DATA=$(sed "$line"'q;d' $file | ansifilter | tr -d $'\r')
            LINE_DATA=${LINE_DATA#*Z}
            LINE_DATA=$(sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' <<< "$LINE_DATA")

            printf "$PRINTF_FORMAT" "$line" "${LINE_DATA:0:$LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_LINE}"

            for (( i=$LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_LINE; i < ${#LINE_DATA}; i=$(($i+$LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_LINE)) )); do
                printf "$PRINTF_FORMAT" " " "${LINE_DATA:$i:$LINE_LENGTH_PRINTF_FORMAT_LINE}"
            done
        done <<< "$MATCHING_LINES"

        perl -E 'say "-" x '"$LINE_LENGTH"
        echo
    done
}

LOG_DIR="build  build"

unzip $FILENAME "$LOG_DIR"'/*' >/dev/null 2>&1

cd "$LOG_DIR"
....
print_content > "$OUT_FN"

echo "Output saved to file '$OUT_FN'"

cd ..
rm -r "$LOG_DIR"
```

Actually, the script doesn't change the contents of `$OUT_FN`. I have tried setting the contents of file named `test-grepped.log` and then running this script, giving output file name as `test-grepped.log`. I checked the contents of the test file both before and after running the script, and they both are same.

When I change

```bash
print_content > "$OUT_FN"
```

to

```bash
print_content
```

and run the script, I get this result (the expected result) in terminal (`Unpacking debconf` is passed as pattern):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ./3builddistro                                                                                                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 90197 | I: Unpacking debconf...                                                                                                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Output saved to file 'test-grepped.log'
```

This confirms that function `print_content` works fine, but redirecting its output to file `$OUT_FN` doesn't work. Redirecting the whole script's output also works as expected. But I wanted that my script itself redirects output to file, instead of doing `./my-script.sh ... > output.log` everytime.

What is the error in my script?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You did not say how you invoke your script, but could it be that you pass as the first parameter a **relative** path, or just a plain file name? In this case, $OUT_FN would be created relative to $LOG_DIR.

Comment: Oh yes! I didn't see that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for information: If you would program your scripts in zsh instead of bash, getting the absolute path would be simplified to `OUT_FN=$1:A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user1934428 commented, I had `cd`'d to `$LOG_DIR`, and then created `$OUT_FN` relative to that dir. Due to this, redirecting to `$OUT_FN` resulted in making a file in `$LOG_DIR`, which I later on deleted by `rm -r $LOG_DIR`.

I resolved this issue by `cd`ing to `$LOG_DIR` inside the function `print_content` only, and later on in the function itself, `cd`ing to `..`.

Comment: A perhaps safer alternative would be to make the filename absolute at the time you create the variable `OUT_FN`, i.e. `OUT_FN=$(readlink -f "$1")`. Then you can cd around in your script as much as you want, without worrying. Or you are doing a `cd -` when you are done with your function. Since you are not running the function in a child process, a mere `cd` inside the function would stay in effect even after the function has returned.

Comment: I am later on `cd`ing to the directory one level above the current directory (as `LOG_DIR` is equal to `"build  build"`). I think it would be better to take absolute path of `OUT_FN` instead. Thank you once again!